# Finding derivative of a function stored in a character array

Tags: c, arrays, character-arrays

What I need to do is read a file which contains equations. I need to take the derivative of each equation and then write those derivative equations in a different .txt file. I've read all the equations into an array of character arrays and now I don't know what to do once I've stored them into the array. I really don't need help writing the equations into another file; I know I can figure that out.

What I need help on is finding a way to taking the derivative of the functions. The type of equations that are going to be read are not that complicated; they're going to be polynomials that don't need the chain rule or quotient rule. There will be, however, *sin x*, *cos x* and *tan x*. Some sample equations that would be read are.

```
-2x^2+2x-3

-2x+sinx-3

-x+sin2x-tanx
```

The trig functions will not have parenthesis and the variable will always be "x".
I just need a push in the right direction, please.

Comment: You'll need to hard code and implement the derivative for each case, ,like `if( strcmp( function, "sinx") == 0 ) strcpy(derivative , "cosx");`, something like that.

Comment: @ArunA.S wrong, why would there be no other way? The cleanest solution probably is parsing the equations, then applying the usual rules of differentiation to the resulting syntax tree.

Comment: well the professor isnt giving us the equations beforehand /:

Answer (score 3):

What you're really asking for is a [parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853136/how-do-i-write-a-parser-in-c-or-objective-c-from-without-a-parser-generators).
A parser is basically a set of rules to read those equations and change/read (parse) each of them.
I'd try to iterate over each line of the file, and differentiate it considering you have a specific character set (i.e ^ means power, x is the parameter, etc.);

For example, some pseudo code:

```
Open the file.
While there's lines to read:
   Read a line - 
   Seperate it by the operands (+,-,/,*)
   For each part:
     Find the power of x,
     Reduce it by one,
     ...(derivating rules) // no way around, you have to implement each function if you want this to work as others mentioned in the comments.
   Reconnect the parts into a string,
   Add it to a list.
 Print each element of the list.
```

If you need help translating that into C, just ask for it; I'll happily help you.

Comment: when you say separate it do you mean into different character arrays??

Comment: @cswolf24 Yes, I do - shorter arrays. you can make a function that recieves such arrays and derivates them seperatley, that'd help you - i'm pretty sure there's something similar to what Michael mentioned that'll fit this purpouse.

Comment: You need to parse into an [abstract syntax tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) then manipulate, i.e. transform, that AST

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do, by the looks of things, is separate the expression into individual *terms* so that you can find the derivative of each in turn.

You can define a term as the largest sequence of characters not containing term separators such as (in your examples) `+` and `-`.

Hence the terms for your examples are:

```
-2x^2+2x-3     =>  2x^2  2x     3
-2x+sinx-3     =>  2x    sinx   3
-x+sin2x-tanx  =>  x     sin2x  tanx
```

For each term, you then need to evaluate the *form* of the term. The form will dictate how you create the derivative.

---

For example, you can detect if it contains a trigonometric function of the form `[n]sin[m]x` where `n` and `m` are optional numbers. To simplify things, you could add in those terms if they're not there, such as `sinx` becoming `1sin1x` (I'll call this the full-form of the term). Being able to assume all subterms are present will greatly ease the derivative calculation.

Let's say the term is `sin4x`. Expanding that will give you `1sin4x` which you can then split into term-multiplier `1`, function `sin` and x-multiplier `4`. Then using standard derivative knowledge `nsinmx => (n*m)cosmx`, this would become `4cos(4x)` and that term would be done.

---

If it *doesn't* contain a trigonometric function, you can use the same full-form trick to cover *all* of the power/constant expressions with the following rules in turn:

- if it's a constant (all numeric), append `x^0` (multiply by 1).
- if it ends with `x`, append `^1`, so `4x` becomes `4x^1`.
- if it starts with `x`, prefix it with `1`, so `x^3` becomes `1x^3`.

Once that's done, you will have a full-form of `ax^b` and you can then create the derivative `(ab)x^(b-1)` and post-process it:

- if the bit after `x` is `^0`, remove the whole `x^0`.
- if the bit after `x` is `^1`, remove the `^1`.
- if the bit before the `x` is `1`, remove it.
- if the bit before the `x` is `0`, remove the entire term (and preceding term separator, if any).

---

So, taking a complex combination of your test data:

```
-2x^2 + 5x + 4sin3x - 3
```

which can be treated as:

```
0 - 2x^2 + 5x + 4sin3x - 3
```

The following actions happen to each term:

```
0      [0x^1]   (derives as) 0, remove it.
2x^2   [2x^2]   (derives as) (2*2)x^(2-1) => 4x^1 => 4x
5x     [5x^1]   (derives as) (5x1)x^(1-1) => 5x^0 => 5
4sin3x [4sin3x] (derives as) 12cos3x
3      [3x^0]   (derives as) 0, remove it and preceding '-'
```

Thus you end up with `- 4x + 5 + 12cos3x` which, although my calculus education is some thirty years in the past (and I don't think I've used it since, though I *will* no doubt be using it next year when my eldest hits secondary school), [Wolfram Alpha appears to agree with me](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative%20of%20-2x%5E2%20%2B%205x%20%2B%204sin%283x%29%20-%203) :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm having difficulty dividing the character array into the individual terms. I was trying to use the strtok() function but its not working out so well ):

Comment: Neat solution from the math side of things... now all that's left is to put all together and give the guy a good parsing algorithm. I'm +1ing you, so you'll have a good motivation to do that if you can (this answer might become useful :)

Answer (score 0):

This function will parse the text, cut it in to different parts identified by `type[i]`, stores in a structure. It recognizes `x`, +, -, and numbers. It can be expand it to include other operators etc.

```
#define maxlen 50

#define idx         0 //X variable
#define idnumber    1 //number
#define idplus      2 //+ sign
#define idminus     3 //- sign

struct foo
{
    int type[10];//each type can be a number (idnum), +, -, etc.
    int num[10];//if type[i] is number then num[i] identifies that number
    int count;//total number of parts
};

void parse_one_line(struct foo *v, const char *s)
{
    char buf[maxlen];
    memset(buf, 0, maxlen);
    int j = 0;
    //remove white spaces
    for (int i = 0, len = strlen(s); i < len; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == ' ') continue;
        buf[j] = s[i];
        j++;
    }

    char part[maxlen];
    v->count = 0;
    for (int i = 0, len = strlen(buf); i < len; i++)
    {
        char c = buf[i];
        if (c == 'x')
        {
            v->type[v->count] = idx;
            v->count++;
        }
        else if (c == '+')
        {
            v->type[v->count] = idplus;
            v->count++;
        }
        else if (c == '-')
        {
            v->type[v->count] = idminus;
            v->count++;
        }
        else if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        {
            int j = 0;
            memset(part, 0, maxlen);
            for (; i < len; i++)
            {
                c = buf[i];
                if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
                {
                    part[j] = c;
                    j++;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            i--;
            v->num[v->count] = atoi(part);
            v->type[v->count] = idnumber;
            v->count++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < v->count; i++)
    {
        switch (v->type[i])
        {
        case idnumber: printf("%d", v->num[i]); break;
        case idx: printf("X"); break;
        case idplus: printf("+"); break;
        case idminus: printf("-"); break;
        default:break;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    struct foo st;
    parse_one_line(&st, "-23x + 2 + 2x - 3");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP was also talking about `sin(x)` if i'm not mistaken.